# Looking for WP 3.0 sample posts data

Tags: wordpress, templates, themes

I'm looking for quality sample posts data for WP 3.0 and up (for theme development). Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test

This has more than the lipsum text; it should have everything you need to see if you've styled the theme entirely and appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use some [Lipsum](http://lipsum.com/) text? They'll let you generate just about as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This question old, but worth to mention that there are plenty of WP plugins for testing with sample post lorem ipsum data. Including images and post formats:

### My choice:

[WP Example Content](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-example-content/)

### Pros:

- It adds six types of posts:

  1. Multiple Paragraph Posts
  2. Image Post
  3. UL and OL Post
  4. Blockquote Post
  5. Post with links
  6. Post with Header tags H1 through H5
- Allows you to remove all the added content with one click
- Formats posts with different styles

### Cons:

- Doesn't add tags
- Doesn't add comments
- Doesn't add categories
- Doesn't add pages

#### Other plugins:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/lorem-ipsum